# broken partition possible for recovery?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I was using copywipe on hirens boot cd to copy a Windows installation to a new drive. unfortunately for me, I was rushing, I set the source drive as the USB drive running hiren/copywipe to the Windows partition, I think it has destroyed the partition tables and replaced with hiren boot USB ones.

disk: was 
NTFS 40 / 250 partitions

disk: now
FAT32 145 / 145 partition

I have used several partition recovery tools, diskdigger to name one, they all show a recovered partition, but its the hiren stuff.

any advice would be a fantastic help

---

To all that have similar issues I recommend using TestDisk (undelete partition) software. you can get this software as part of hirens boot cd.

see answer

Comment: If you've overwritten the partition, your chances of recovery are slim to none.

Comment: RP - i was actually lucky i think. im not entirely 100% but it looks as if they don't overlap - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seek and download: hirens boot cd. [Hirens Book CD Website](http://www.hiren.info)

Boot into MiniXP
Start HBCD Menu > Menu > Recovery > TestDisk (undelete partition)

I followed these steps to recovery MY partitions

Create New Log File
Select a media (use Arro keys, then press Enter)

- Disk /dev/sda - 320GB / 298 GiB - WDC
  .... [THIS IS THE DISK I WANT TO
  RECOVER
- Disk /dev/sdc - 8401 MB / 8012 MiB - SMI USB ... [ HIREN BOOT CD USB   ]
  Now Proceed

  - Proceed >

---

Select partition table type:

NTFS uses Intel - specifically used for PC's

Analyse the current partition structure it will give you details specific to your drive.

It found my NTFS partition which now have something called bad relative sectors. i will now investigate how to fix this.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer by clicking the outline of the check mark next to it. This tells others that your problem is resolved.